# How do I get permission ID of the person who last edited the file with Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I need unique identifications of person who made last change in files, but in files 
[https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource] has only field "lastModifyingUserName".

Is it possible to get permission ID of the person who last edited the file with Google Drive API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is missing, and I'd say it is a bug.

The permission ID should be added here so that at least some cross-referencing. I will investigate the possibility of this. Thanks for raising the issue.